# Joining two table into 1 table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, join

Here I have two tables. One is called `table1` and has a column `word`, which is of datatype `varchar(500)` and looks like

```
a
pen
book
like
nice
.....
```

Another table is `table2` and has a column `meaning` of datatype `ntext` and looks like

```
 one
 a long thin object used for writing  
 reading material 
 to enjoy  
 pleasant
 .......
```

Now I want to join table1 and table2  and with them make a another table `table3`

`table3` will have two columns that are `word` and `meaning`" column and will look like

```
a      one
pen    a long thin object used for writing 
book   reading material 
like   to enjoy 
nice   pleasant
.....  .......
```

How can I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: do u have any sort of link between these two tables?? it would be helpful if you show table structure also?

Comment: You have to have a new column in the second table something like `ObjectId` as a foreign key to the table1 name. But why not store them in only one table?

Comment: my database is a dictionary database.first table contains english words  and second table contains their respective meaning.@TilT

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You better have a [PRIMARY KEY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) column in table1 (lets call it terms) and  a [FOREIGN KEY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) column in table2 (lets call it definitions). Then you can join both tables using these columns to get your result

```sql
SELECT term, definition
  FROM terms t LEFT JOIN 
       definitions d ON t.termid = d.termid
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82113/1)

IMHO there is no need for table3. You just use a query like this to get desired result.

This way if need be you can store more than one definition per term.